# Laravel 9 relations with subquery

Tags: laravel, subquery, relationship, laravel-9

I'm working on an educational game, this is basically the scheme:
[image]

Important: I need a question to be in multiple languages.
That is, a game will have many questions. And each question will have many languages.

Models:
Game, GameQuestion, QuestionGroup, Question, Languague

Relationships:

Game:

```
public function game_questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(GameQuestion::class);
}
```

GameQuestion:

```
public function question_groups()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(QuestionGroup::class, 'questions','question_group_id');
}
```

QuestionGroup:

```
public function questions()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
}
```

Question:

```
public function language()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Language::class);
}
```

Language:

```
public function questions()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
}
```

How can I retrieve with a search the collection of questions (many languages) added to the game?

```
$games = Game::where('user_id', $user_id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->with('game_question_question_group')->get();
```

I've already tried some consultations but I haven't had any luck. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but looking at the provided ERD. I think you should turn `game_questions` into `game_question` as a pivot between `games` and `questions` That way a game can have many questions and vice versa. While questions still belong to question_groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use nested relationships:

```
$games = Game::where('user_id', $user_id)->with('game_questions.question_groups.questions')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Read more about it here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading

But honestly, the database could be designed better

Comment: I really thank you for your time. I will calmly review your suggestion. What do you suggest regarding the database?